# Java: Read .csv file and save into arrays

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have a problem with an exception while I am trying to read a .csv file and save each column into array.
Although, it may seem long program, it isn't. I just have 15 different arrays.

This is the exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2" in the row

> department[i] = dataArray[2];

Is there something that I could do?

```
      BufferedReader CSVFile = 
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Sub-Companies.csv"));

      String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
      // Read the number of the lines in .csv file 
      // i = row of the .csv file
      int i = 0; 
      while (dataRow != null){
          i++;
          dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();

        }
      System.out.println(i);
      // Close the file once all data has been read.
      CSVFile.close();

      // End the printout with a blank line.
      System.out.println();

      // Save into arrays
      customer_id = new String[i];
      company_name = new String[i];
      department = new String[i];
      employer = new String[i];
      country = new String[i];
      zipcode = new String[i];
      address = new String[i];
      city = new String[i];
      smth1 = new String[i];
      smth2 = new String[i];
      phone_no1 = new String[i];
      phone_no2 = new String[i];
      email = new String[i];
      website = new String[i];
      customer_no = new String[i];

      // Read first line.
      // The while checks to see if the data is null. If 
      // it is, we've hit the end of the file. If not, 
      // process the data.
      int j;
      int counter;
      i = 0;

      // Read the file again to save the data into arrays
      BufferedReader CSV = 
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Sub-Companies.csv"));

      String data = CSV.readLine();

      while (data != null){
          String[] dataArray = data.split(";");
          for (String item:dataArray) {
            customer_id[i] = dataArray[0];
            company_name[i] = dataArray[1];
            department[i] = dataArray[2];
            employer[i] = dataArray[3];
            country[i] = dataArray[4];
            zipcode[i] = dataArray[5];
            address[i] = dataArray[6];
            city[i] = dataArray[7];
            smth1[i] = dataArray[8];
            smth2[i] = dataArray[9];
            phone_no1[i] = dataArray[10];
            phone_no2[i] = dataArray[11];
            email[i] = dataArray[12];
            website[i] = dataArray[13];
            customer_no[i] = dataArray[14];
            }


          //System.out.print(address[i] + "\n"); 
          data = CSV.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
          i++;
      }
```

Thank you in advance!

Some data is "E3B3C5EB-B101-4C43-8E0C-ADFE76FC87FE;"Var Welk"  Inh. Kar;NULL;NULL;DE;16278;Rotr  3;AngermÃ¼nde;NULL;NULL;03331/354348-0;0343331/364548-15;info@aalls.com;http://www.adss.com;ipo241", but there could differ (smaller or bigger).

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use a CSV parsing library like Super CSV or my favorite, opencsv.

Comment: That error is thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index greater than or equal to the size of the array.

Comment: Will this help to me prevent the exception? I was thinking of something try, catch, but the problem is that I want to be sure that the data is saved correctly

Comment: Please show csv file content...

Comment: @EmmanuelN Yeap, I have read what this exception is, but I cannot find why this problem occurs

Comment: CVS files can be with other separators. Most likely ";" is not the deliminator in your case. have you tried ",".

Comment: Please show  file content it will make clarification.........

Comment: @sunleo I just edited the question

Comment: @EmmanuelN it is actually ";"

Comment: After `String[] dataArray = data.split(";");` do `System.out.println("array elements: " + dataArray.length);`

Comment: what is the size of `department` and `dataArray` ??

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR you can see the size of department

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR dataArray is 15 and department is the size of lines of my cvs file.

Comment: @DimitraMicha okay, just for debugging purposes comment out             //department[i] = dataArray[2]; and see you are able to access the other indexes(which i am sure you would not).

Comment: is it bcoz the value is null?

Comment: @mcalex Sorry guys, I have just found that there are two entries with 2 and 14 length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best is use `ArraList<String>` and if you want `convert as Array`.

your problem is you are counting no of lines to create array size but you are adding data
based on split(";") so there is mismatch in array length and available values to add in array from split(";").

Comment: Please explain more, will this prevent the exception?

Comment: gh;ghj;ghjk;ghj; for example like this you have two lines , when you are about to create array ,you use row count as 2 for array size.but when you split(";"), its size is 4 and you try to add 4 values to array which can have only 2 values. so there will be  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.Thats all.

Comment: Now I am confused, in each array I save one entry from each row. So the entries are equal to the lines of the file, no?

Comment: @Dimitra but you said they were all 15

Comment: @mcalex after the print you proposed, yes, they are all 15:(

Comment: see you have 2 rows ,  you create array with size of 2.but by splitting single row it gives 4 values or more than 2.When you try to add 4 values to array which can have 2 values ,Exception occurs.

Comment: check your code inside of while you have for loop.So print size of any one of your arrays , its size will be less than count 15.That is the problem.

Comment: Sorry @mcalex I have some different entries.

Comment: @DimitraMicha please print customer_id.length and i value at the end of your code . you will be free from this problem.And let us know.

Comment: @sunleo I understand what you are saying. Is it good to say if that if the length is less that 14, put the other entries as NULL?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19687/discussion-between-sunleo-and-dimitra-micha)

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick: it basically creates a matrix representation of the csv file.

```
LinkedList<String[]> rows = new LinkedList<String[]>();
String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
// Read the number of the lines in .csv file 
// i = row of the .csv file
int i = 0; 
while ((datarow = CSVFile.readLine()) != null){
    i++;
    rows.addLast(dataRow.split(","));
}

String[][] csvMatrix = rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()][]);
```

In csvMatrix[row][col]...

When accessing to a column, assert that the col number you are trying to access is in range by doing :

```
if(col < csvMatrix[row].length)
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I don't get how if(col < csvMatrix[row].length) works

Comment: Sorry I missed some info on this line:
It's not because one row has X columns that all rows will have the same amount...
So to be cautious, before trying to access an index, validate that the index exists: In your situation, the row might be invalid, therefore you may want to even ignore adding it to the list...so instead of having "rows.addLast(dataRow.split(","));" in the loop, you may have this:
String[] temp = dataRow.split(",");
if(temp.length == ACCEPTED_COLUMN_COUNT) {
    rows.addLast(temp);
}

Comment: hey @doctor killer. I just solved my issue. Thank you a lot for your response.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code.  The exception is caused by the fact that one of the lines doesn't contain enough of the ';' separated values.

The strange thing about your code is this bit:

```
  for (String item:dataArray) {
    customer_id[i] = dataArray[0];
```

This simply means you repeat the same assignments 15 times (just remove the for (String item: ...)).

If I were you, I'd do the following:

create a class; something like this:

```
public class Customer {
    private String customerId;
    private String companyName;

    // ...
    public static Customer create(final String... args) {
        if (args.length != 15) {
            return null; // or throw an exception
        }
        final Customer rv = new Customer();
        rv.setCustomerId(args[0]);
        rv.setCompanyName(args[1]);
        // ...
        return rv;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(final String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(final String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
}
```

use collection (as suggested in post above):

```
    BufferedReader csv = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Sub-Companies.csv"));
    List<Customer> customers = new LinkedList<Customer>();

    String data;
    while ((data = csv.readLine()) != null){
        Customer customer = Customer.create(data.split(";"));
        if (customer != null) {
            customers.add(customer);
        }
    }
```

If you require array instead of collection, you can do:

```
Customer[] arr = customers.toArray(new Customer[customers.size()]);
```

Use a library to to read the file...  You can try http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ for example.

Comment: I was thinking of using `if (args.length != 15) {
            return null; // or throw an exception ` this also and then save each these arrays as array[15] with the other entries NULL

Answer (score 1):

```
department[i] = dataArray[2];
```

The exception means that the `dataArray` does not have that much elements (i.e. 3).
If you want to parse your CSV file you can make your life easier by specifying that for any missing elements there must be a placeholder.
What I mean is that you can have a record like:

`a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;j`
Where each of the characters represent the values of your columns **but** when an element is missing the format **must** be:
`a;;;;;f;g;h;j` and **not** `a;f;g;h;j`

This is not an unusual expectation but the norm in CSV files and would simplify your code a lot and would avoid array index exception as your line will always have the expected columns

Comment: "If you want to parse your CSV file you can make your life easier by specifying that for any missing elements there must be a placeholder." I understand what you mean, but is there a way to do that? Maybe, I could read how many times ";" appears and then add ";" if it is missing.

Comment: But how are your CSV files are generated?If manually then just add the extraneous `;` for each missing element. Same if you generate them by code.So when you parse the CSV line when you do `split(';')` you *know* the size of the returned array

Comment: This cvs file is given to me. Yeap, when I split it I know it.

Comment: If it is given to you, you should specify the expectations on the csv format

Answer (score 1):

Using ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parseDataFromCsvFile()
{
     ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataFromFile=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
     try{
         Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new FileReader("CSV_FILE_PATH"));
         scanner.useDelimiter(";");

         while(scanner.hasNext())
         {
            String dataInRow=scanner.nextLine();
            String []dataInRowArray=dataInRow.split(";");
            ArrayList<String> rowDataFromFile=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dataInRowArray));
            dataFromFile.add(rowDataFromFile);
         }
         scanner.close();
     }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return dataFromFile;
}
```

Calling the method(displaying csv content):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> csvFileData=parseDataFromCsvFile();

public void printCsvFileContent(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> csvFileData)
{
    for(ArrayList<String> rowInFile:csvFileData)
    {
        System.out.println(rowInFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load data into a Parameterized JUnit test using Gradle ( instead of Maven) , here is the method:

```
// import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
@Parameters(name = "{0}: {1}: {2}")
public static Iterable<String[]> loadTestsFromFile2() {
    String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    File tFile = loadGradleResource( System.getProperty("user.dir") + 
        separator +  "build" + separator + "resources" + separator +  "test" + 
            separator + "testdata2.csv" );
    List<String[]> rows = null;
    if ( tFile.exists() ) {
        CSVReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new CSVReader( new FileReader( tFile ), ',' );
            rows = reader.readAll();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
    staticlogger.info("Finished loadTestsFromFile2()");
    return rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if `java.util.StringTokenizer` helps

Example:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputString, ";")
```

Manual: [StringTokenizer docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)